# how to explode the index of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have an array like

```
Array
(
    [select_value_2_1] =>  7
)
```

I want to explode index into `Array ([0]=select_value, [1]=2, [2]=1)`

Comment: explode it. what's the problem?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel how to explode an index? a string can be exploded.

Comment: @maniclorn the key(index) is also a string in this case

Comment: Put the split key into a temporary variable. Ordinary PHP arrays can only have scalar keys.

Comment: You need to come up with a stronger definition of when to split the key. Apparently there are `_` that should split and some that shouldn't. How to keep them apart?

Comment: There is no "array key" variable type in PHP. **What particular problem you have with splitting this string?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use `explode()` because it will also separate `select` from `value`. You could alter your output so that instead you have array keys like `selectValue_2_1`.

Then you can do what you want:

```
$items = array('selectValue_2_1' => 1);

foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    $parts = explode('_', $key);
}
```

That will yield, for example:

```
array('selectValue', '2', '1');
```

You can use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to extract the keys from an array.

Comment: Thanks @Daren Chandisingh. I should use selectValue insteadselect_value.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_keys` to get your keys:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Or use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($elements as $key => $value){
   print_r (explode("_", $key));
}
```

Comment: This would rip apart `select_value` as well.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig But the question in this case is how to get the key as a string so that OP can use standard operations on it

Comment: And then he will create another question and ask for how to get the array the way he wants it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to split the keys as in your example, use a more complex function:

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {

    $key_parts = preg_split('/_(?=\d)/', $key);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have the exact pattern, you could use a regular expression to extract the values:

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if(preg_match('/(select_value)_(\d+)_(\d+)/', $key, $result)) {
          array_shift($result); // remove full match
    }
}
```

The performance of this may suck because you have a regular expression *and* an array operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr=array("select_value_2_1" => 7);
$keys= array_keys($arr);
$key=$keys[0];
$new_arr=explode("_",$key);
print_r($new_arr);
?>
```